# Ethereum from cold wallet, how?

Tags: cold-storage

I moved my Ethereum out of my coinbase account and to a cold wallet/address. My question is, how do I get it out of cold storage so I can trade with someone?

Comment: What form is the cold wallet in? Private keys on an air-gapped PC? QR code? etc.?

Comment: I have the private key public key and 24 word pass phrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright guys, I have found the answer to my question, I am posting it here so if anyone else has the same question, they can find the answer. I was able to find an app that lets me import my cold storage address using either the private key or the mnemonic phrase called imtoken. After installing the app I gained access to my ETH.

Comment: WARNING: For anyone else using this... Feeding your keys into a third-party app gives that app full access to your funds. Before doing such a thing, check if the code for the app is available and auditable. Open-source is better than closed-source.

Comment: For IMToken specifically, two things worry me. The GitHub repository is empty (https://github.com/consenlabs/imToken), and the company who created the app is Chinese, which could make dealing with any problems all the more difficult (both on a legal level and a general communication level).

Comment: I only used it to send my ETH back to coinbase

Comment: Yep, understood, and if you succeeded in doing that, that's great. However, you have no way of knowing what the app might have done with your keys. Unless you're able to see the code for yourself, and work out exactly how their app works, you're putting your trust into an unknown. It could still be the case that the app took a copy of your keys, recorded anything else it needed to know, and sent the details back to the mothership. I'd suggest not using that particular account again, just to be safe :-)

Comment: I don't plan on it, I'm also not worried if what I have gets taken. It was only like $7.95 so no big loss, I can get that back with an hour's work at McDonald's or something lol

Comment: Okay, no big issues then :-) But for anyone else who might be about to transfer bigger amounts, the warning might be useful.

Comment: Oh Lord yeah, I'm new to crypto currency so I was experimenting with $10 to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction) to send your ethers.

On every exchanges you can find an address used to received your ethers. Just send ethers to this address. ( It is not the address that sent you ethers to your cold wallet )

It will not be really different than the process you followed to withdraw your ethers in the first place. Make sure address is correct(0x...), amount and leave the data field empty. Here a good guide with screenshots [how to use MyEtherWallet](https://www.cryptocompare.com/wallets/guides/how-to-use-myetherwallet/)

Always test before with very small amount before

Comment: MyEtherWallet won't let me import my address with the private key I have from an airgapped pc